# Adding express and Mongo for models and db schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a web application and using grunt for managing tasks. 
This is the package.json file that I am using. Now I need to include express and mongodb schema for this application.

Using npm install express and npm install mongoose, will all the dependencies get installed automatically or should individual commands be used?

Help me out with this. Thanks.

```
{
  "name": "square",
  "version": "3.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect-livereload": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~3.0.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.13.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jade": "~0.15.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-injector": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.3",
    "grunt-usemin": "~3.1.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.1.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.4.0",
    "time-grunt": "~1.3.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.10.0",
    "http-errors": "^1.3.1",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "depd": "^1.1.0",
    "destroy": "^1.0.3",
    "range-parser": "^1.0.3",
    "mime": "^1.3.4",
    "fresh": "^0.3.0",
    "etag": "^1.7.0",
    "ms": "^0.7.1",
    "on-finished": "^2.3.0",
    "statuses": "^1.2.1"    
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
npm install express --save-dev 
npm install mongoose --save-dev
```

This will save to your devDepencies list in the package.json file. Any dependencies that express or mongoose need will automatically be installed when you install each.

Answer (score 0):

use following commands:

```
npm install express --save
npm install mongoose --save
```

this will install all dependencies to package.json and if you want to install them on other system you can use

```
npm install
```

this will install all dependencies mentioned in package.json.